# C++ midfunction hook overwrites original local variables

Tags: c++, x86, inline-assembly

I wrote a mid function hook and I noticed that the original local variables of the function are being overwritten by the variables I declared in my function.

Here is my code:

```
DWORD jbPlantTrap = 0x48ED53 + 7;
DWORD jbPlantTrapSkip = 0x48EDD6;
__declspec(naked) void hkPlantTrap()
{
    __asm
    {
        PUSHAD
        PUSHFD
    }

    // this variable is overwriting the original [EBP-4]
    unsigned char* player;
    unsigned char* packet;

    __asm
    {
        MOV ECX, DWORD PTR SS : [EBP + 0x8]
        MOV player, ECX
        MOV EDX, DWORD PTR SS : [EBP + 0x0C]
        MOV packet, EDX
    }

    if (*(WORD*)(packet + 2) == 114 && sub_46261E(player, 104))
    {
        __asm
        {
            POPFD
            POPAD

            JMP[jbPlantTrapSkip]
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // go back to original jump
        __asm
        {
            POPFD
            POPAD

            MOV DWORD PTR SS : [EBP - 0x34] , 0x0

            JMP[jbPlantTrap]
        }
    }
}
```

How can I prevent it from doing that so what ever variables I declare on my detour doesn't affect the original function at all?

Like how `player` is overwriting `[EBP-4]` and messing up the variables on the original function causing strange behaviors.

My hooking function for reference:

```
void __cdecl PlaceJMP(BYTE *pAddress, DWORD dwJumpTo, DWORD dwLen) 
{
    DWORD dwOldProtect, dwBkup, dwRelAddr;
    VirtualProtect(pAddress, dwLen, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &dwOldProtect);
    dwRelAddr = (DWORD)(dwJumpTo - (DWORD)pAddress) - 5;
    *pAddress = 0xE9;
    *((DWORD *)(pAddress + 0x1)) = dwRelAddr;
    for (DWORD x = 0x5; x < dwLen; x++)
        *(pAddress + x) = 0x90;
    VirtualProtect(pAddress, dwLen, dwOldProtect, &dwBkup);
}
```

Source in question:

```
CPU Disasm
Address   Hex dump          Command                                  Comments
0048ED53  |> \C745 CC 00000 MOV DWORD PTR SS:[LOCAL.13],0
0048ED5A  |.  EB 09         JMP SHORT 0048ED65
0048ED5C  |>  8B4D CC       /MOV ECX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-34]
0048ED5F  |.  83C1 01       |ADD ECX,1
0048ED62  |.  894D CC       |MOV DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-34],ECX
0048ED65  |>  837D CC 02    |CMP DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-34],2
0048ED69  |.  73 6B         |JNB SHORT 0048EDD6
0048ED6B  |.  8B55 CC       |MOV EDX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-34]
0048ED6E  |.  8B45 08       |MOV EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+8]
0048ED71  |.  66:8B8C50 E43 |MOV CX,WORD PTR DS:[EDX*2+EAX+37E4]
0048ED79  |.  51            |PUSH ECX                                ; /Arg1
0048ED7A  |.  E8 11E8FFFF   |CALL 0048D590                           ; \file.0048D590
0048ED7F  |.  83C4 04       |ADD ESP,4
0048ED82  |.  8945 D4       |MOV DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-2C],EAX
0048ED85  |.  837D D4 00    |CMP DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-2C],0
0048ED89  |.^ 74 49         |JE SHORT 0048EDD4
0048ED8B  |.  8B55 D4       |MOV EDX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-2C]
0048ED8E  |.  33C0          |XOR EAX,EAX
0048ED90  |.  66:8B82 3A270 |MOV AX,WORD PTR DS:[EDX+273A]
0048ED97  |.  8B4D E4       |MOV ECX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-1C]
0048ED9A  |.  81E1 FFFF0000 |AND ECX,0000FFFF
0048EDA0  |.  3BC1          |CMP EAX,ECX
0048EDA2  |.^ 75 30         |JNE SHORT 0048EDD4
0048EDA4  |.  8B55 D4       |MOV EDX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-2C]
0048EDA7  |.  33C0          |XOR EAX,EAX
0048EDA9  |.  66:8B82 4B270 |MOV AX,WORD PTR DS:[EDX+274B]
0048EDB0  |.  8B4D 08       |MOV ECX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+8]
0048EDB3  |.  33D2          |XOR EDX,EDX
0048EDB5  |.  66:8B51 0C    |MOV DX,WORD PTR DS:[ECX+0C]
0048EDB9  |.  3BC2          |CMP EAX,EDX
0048EDBB  |.^ 75 17         |JNE SHORT 0048EDD4
0048EDBD  |.  6A 05         |PUSH 5                                  ; /Arg2 = 5
0048EDBF  |.  8B45 08       |MOV EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+8]            ; |
0048EDC2  |.  66:8B48 0C    |MOV CX,WORD PTR DS:[EAX+0C]             ; |
0048EDC6  |.  51            |PUSH ECX                                ; |Arg1
0048EDC7  |.  E8 A3FEFFFF   |CALL 0048EC6F                           ; \file.0048EC6F
0048EDCC  |.  83C4 08       |ADD ESP,8
0048EDCF  |.  E9 22030000   |JMP 0048F0F6
0048EDD4  |>^ EB 86         \JMP SHORT 0048ED5C
0048EDD6  |>  C745 B8 00000 MOV DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-48],0
```

---

**UPDATE**

Moving the variable declarations outside the function makes it work as expected but I wanted to avoid this. What other options do I have?

```
DWORD jbPlantTrap = 0x48ED53 + 7;
DWORD jbPlantTrapSkip = 0x48EDD6;
unsigned char* player1; // moved outside function
unsigned char* packet1; // moved outside function
__declspec(naked) void hkPlantTrap() {
...
```

Comment: IIRC, a naked function's entire body has to be written in asm.  Using C variables and statements will lead to compiler-generated code without having done any proper setup.  Also, your own asm uses `[EBP + 0x8]` for something but you never set EBP to point at anything.

Comment: @PeterCordes printing out `player` and `packet` actually shows that it points to the correct variables so I believe the `[EBP]` is set correctly. Also I have other similar functions to this, which works, but it still does replace the original function variables. Fortunately those overwritten variables are not the important so it doesn't mess with the behavior. Unfortunately this one overwrites an important variable.

Answer (score 2):

When using a mid function hook and a declspec naked function you must write it all in assembly.  You should declare any variables outside of the naked function and then reference these variables in your assembly instead so you aren't corrupting the stack.

Alternatively you could increase the stack size, do your stuff and then unwind the stack before you return but this would be more annoying to be honest.

Comment: I did try doing a `prolog` and `epilog` by saving esp and sub'ng it hoping I could get extra space for the variables. 8 bytes in my case of 2 int pointers but it didn't seem to work at all. Just using variables outside the function worked but I'm a bit worried about multi threads accessing the global variables.

Comment: @majidarif I've been doing this a long time and never had any problem with multithreading, but it's possible it could be a problem in the future.  I would cross that bridge when you get there, IMO